# ERD Multi-user level access under a single account

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, erd

Currently I have the following database design

A user is either a person or a business entity. How do I extend this database design so that under a single business account, a business can allow for multi user access?

Example a business might want to give access their control panel access to an accountant, a developer, etc... A developer should only be able to view and manage applications while an accountant can view / download transactions etc...

```
USER
Id
Name
Username
Password
...




PERSONAL_INFO
UserId (PK-FK)
FirstName
MiddleName
LastName
....


BUSINESS_INFO
UserId (PK-FK)
BusinessName
....
```

---

Would this do it?

```
USER_ACCESS?
Id
BusinessUserId 
GrantedUserId

USER_PERMISSION
Id
UserAccessId
PermissionId

PERMISSION
Id
Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think, it's better to add the entity BUSINESS_INFO  and the attribute BusinessInfoId (foreign key to BUSINESS_INFO table) to USER table. The BUSINESS_GROUP table will have the primary key BusinessInfoId (of int type, e.g.)

```
USER
UserId
BusinessInfoId (FK)
Name
Username
Password
FirstName
MiddleName
LastName
...

BUSINESS_INFO
BusinessInfoId (PK)
BusinessName
....
```

notice, PERSONAL_INFO table is redundant. its fields must be normalized in USER table

Comment: Hmm that would mean 1 user can only belong to 1 business, might be have USER_GROUP inside there you have UserId and BusinessInfo.

Comment: if you need "many business - to many users" relation, then of course, you need connection table like USER_GROUP. in this case you don't need a BusinessInfoId field in USER table